# How to check is Screen pinning is Enabled from Settings or not Programatically?

Tags: android-screen-pinning

i want to know how to check is screen pinning/pin window option is enabled from Setting or not ? if any one know how to do that programatically, please let me know.
And Sorry for my bad english, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have an answer to the question but I discovered that app can pin itself with `startLockTask` method even if the Screen pinning switch in Settings/Security is OFF. User can opt out on the system provided dialog, so if this is why you're thinking about this setting, as I were, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: I did it but screen pinning doesn't hide the popups.